# What is the Expire on apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, swf

I'd like to set the following:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/x-flash-swf  "access plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash  "access plus 1 days"
<FilesMatch "\.swf$">
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

but I usually set on html

```
<embed src="http://example.com/flash/example.swf?YYYYMMDDSS" />
```

What is the difference YYYYMMDDSS and Expires(mod_expires)?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference YYYYMMDDSS and Expires(mod_expires)?

mod_expires sets the headers in the HTTP protocol, and most caching servers which follow the HTTP specs do exactly what you request with the correct headers.

Using a query parameter with a date as part of a URL, and thus the corresponding GET request doesn't set any expiration.  You are depending on the browser to operate the way you expect.  This is a bit of a hack and is somewhat uncommon, but I suspect it works.

You can do both if you like.

Answer (score 1):

"YYYYMMDDSS" will not be cached proxy server.

You can manual update user cache, change "YYYYMMDDSS".

Comment: Thank you so much . but  only that ?

Comment: You can manual update user cache, change YYYYMMDDSS.

Comment: I believe I have seen proxy servers cache things with query parameters included as part of the URL in a GET request.

Comment: By default Squid and other Windows proxy don't cache.